# Change header background colour when page scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css, colortransform

I've been looking at a solution for this but I cannot get it to work.

I would like my page header to change from a transparent background to a white background as the user begins scrolling the page.

HTML code is:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="topbar"></div>
    <div class="sitelogo"></div>
    <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/iamdanmorris"><em>Twitter</em></a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code is:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
    background-color:transparent;   
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried that, no.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".header").addClass("active");
    } else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
       $(".header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/634d6vgq/2/

This will add the `background-color: #fff` to the element if user has scrolled more than 50 pixels from the top

This will add a class "active" so you can style it within the css (easier to maintain)

**edit:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".header").addClass("active");
        } else {
            //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
           $(".header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

And your css:

```
.active { background-color: #fff}
```

Make sure you also add this css rule, orherwise the background color will not change

Comment: Place this script at the bottom of the page to make sure that the elements are loaded. Did you created a class in your css where you style the active header? (For example: .active {background-color: #fff}) if you haven't please add this small code and if it doesn't works than please see the edit

Comment: the only problem i have now is i would really like to have white nav text on transparent background and grey text on white background when scrolled. Do you think you could help? @sakesalverda

Comment: .header {color:#fff;background-color:transparent;} and .header.active {color:#777;background-color:#fff} and if my complete answer helped you please mark my answer so the discussion is closed

Comment: I am currently using this code for my site and it works perfectly. 
Can I also add the active class to make the logo change as well as menu link color?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my straightforward solution for this topic. You just need to add an ID to the element to change color. In my case, elementor gives the id as "header_frame" in Advance Tab.

Put the below code into the footer:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        jQuery('#header_frame').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    } else {
       jQuery('#header_frame').css('background-color', '#EFF2F4');
    }
});
```

No need to add some class like 'active' etc.

Comment: Please avoid linking to your personal site unless it's directly relevant to the asked question. It can look a lot like spam when you share an unsolicited link like that.