# How to change header color on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

my site is using WordPress v `5.0.3` along with Vantage `1.8.3` child theme. I am trying to change the header color while the user scrolls down.

I searched for similar posts to reach a solution. However, I might have done something wrong. I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

First, I added a js file in /wp-admin/js/header-active.js containing this:

```
$(function() {
        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $(".site-header").addClass("active");
            } else {
                //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
               $(".site-header").removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
```

Then I added this code to my child theme's functions.php file

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'header-active',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/header-ative.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

At last, I edited my CSS to change header's as js describes
but no effect took place at all.

You can self inspect my issue here: https://websitevisuals.com

Any suggestion to reach a solution would be highly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should always start your debugging by looking into the browser console. In this instance, it would have told you that `https://websitevisuals.com/wp-content/themes/vantage-childpublic_html/websitevisuals/wp-admin/js/header-ative.js?ver=5.0.3` could not be loaded, but resulted in a 404 Not Found only.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266651/change-header-background-colour-when-page-scrolls

Comment: your script should be inlcuded in active theme js. not in wp-admin folder

Comment: `header-active.js` or `header-ative.js`? you need to move js file to your child theme. https://websitevisuals.com/wp-admin/js/header-active.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Problem is in js file you have included.

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/header-ative.js',
```

should be

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/header-active.js',
```